# Multiple Warnings when testing a component with React Testing Library and Jest

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I am new in the testing world and I have spent days trying to figure out how to unit test a signup screen in React Native (with Expo) using React Testing Library. When i run my script to run the tests `npm run test` I get an endless list of warnings in the console. I am using React Hook Forms to make the signup form and NativeBase as a UI framework.

**How can I get rid of these warnings?** Maybe I need to mock some components? Any guidance on how to test this screen would be helpful. Thank you so much.

Some examples of these warnings are:

```
console.error
    Warning: <Text /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

```
console.error
    Warning: React does not recognize the `accessibilityDescribedBy` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `accessibilitydescribedby` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

```
 console.error
    Warning: The tag <RNCSafeAreaProvider> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

Here is my entry point App.tsx

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';
import SignUp from './src/screens/signUp/signUp';
import UploadAvatar from './src/screens/uploadAvatar';

type RootStackParamList = {
    signUp: undefined;
    uploadAvatar: undefined;
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="signUp">
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="signUp"
                        component={SignUp}
                        options={{ title: 'Registro' }}
                    />
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="uploadAvatar"
                        component={UploadAvatar}
                        options={{
                            animation: 'slide_from_right',
                            title: 'Foto de perfil'
                        }}
                    />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
}

export default App
```

Here is my screen testing file (I am just trying to get my first test to work).

```
import React from "react";
import { SignUp } from "./signUp";
import { NativeBaseProvider } from "native-base";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import user from "@testing-library/user-event"

const inset = {
  frame: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 },
  insets: { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
};

describe("SignUpForm", () => {
  const {getByLabelText} = render(<NativeBaseProvider initialWindowMetrics={inset}><SignUp /></NativeBaseProvider>);
  describe("With invalid inputs", () => {
    it ("fails with invalid first name", () => {
      const firstName = getByLabelText("Nombre")
      user.type(firstName, "123Diego" )
      user.click(screen.getByRole("button"))
    })
    it ("fails with invalid last name", () => {
      expect(0).toBe(1)
    })
    it ("fails with invalid birthday", () => {
      expect(0).toBe(1)
    })
    it ("fails with invalid email", () => {
      expect(0).toBe(1)
    })
    it ("fails with invalid email confirmation", () => {
      expect(0).toBe(1)
    })
    it ("fails with invalid password", () => {
      expect(0).toBe(1)
    })
    it ("fails with invalid password confirmation", () => {
      expect(0).toBe(1)
    })
  })
  it ("makes only one API call successfully with valid inputs", () => {
    expect(0).toBe(1)
  })
});
```

My jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    preset: "jest-expo",
    globals: {
      "ts-jest": {
        tsconfig: {
          jsx: "react"
        }
      }
    },
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    testMatch: [
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts?(x)"
    ],
    collectCoverage: false,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
      "**/*.{ts,tsx}",
      "!**/coverage/**",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/babel.config.js",
      "!**/jest.setup.js"
    ],
    moduleFileExtensions: [
      "js",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|sentry-expo|native-base)"
    ],
    coverageReporters: [
      "json-summary", 
      "text",
      "lcov"
    ],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest.setup.ts"]
  };
```

And my jest.setup.ts

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom"
import { server } from "./src/mocks/server"
import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';

beforeAll(() => server.listen({
    onUnhandledRequest: "error"
}))
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => server.close())


jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () => {
    const Reanimated = require('react-native-reanimated/mock');

    // The mock for `call` immediately calls the callback which is incorrect
    // So we override it with a no-op
    Reanimated.default.call = () => { };

    return Reanimated;
});

// Silence the warning: Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');
```